# Register IIdentityServerInteractionService in Identity Server 4 for OpenID Connect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm trying to follow this tutorial on [Adding User Authentication with OpenID Connect](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html) from the Identity Server 4 docs but I get the following error when I start up the mvc client:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IdentityServer4.Services.IIdentityServerInteractionService' while attempting to activate 'IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.HomeController'.

How do I go about registering the **Identity Server Interaction Service**? Its sounds like an issue with DI.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You get this error when there is no implementation available of the interface `IIdentityServerInteractionService` in the dependency injection container.
The HomeController of the Quickstart example requests for an implementation of `IIdentityServerInteractionService` in the constructor:

```
public HomeController(IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction)
{
    _interaction = interaction;
}
```

You should add `services.AddIdentityServer();` in the `ConfigureServices` method in your startup class. IdentityServer will inject an implementation of `IIdentityServerInteractionService`, namingly the `DefaultIdentityServerInteractionService`.